# How to create a PARQUET format table in SPARK using JDBC data source with SPARK-SQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

As per [Spark CREATE TABLE LIKE](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-create-table-like.html), I’m trying to create a parquet format table using jdbc data source. Something like:

```
CREATE TABLE `PARQUET_MY_TABLE`
LIKE `MY_TABLE`
USING org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc
OPTIONS (
  url "jdbc:mysql://XX.XX.XX.XX:3306/test?useSSL=FALSE&nullCatalogMeansCurrent=true&zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull",
  driver "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver",
  dbtable `MY_TABLE`",
  user "username",
  password "password"
)
STORED AS PARQUET;
```

It is giving the following error:

```
SQL Error [42000]: org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error running query: [PARSE_SYNTAX_ERROR] org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException: 
    Syntax error at or near 'OPTIONS'(line 4, pos 0)
    == SQL ==
    CREATE TABLE PARQUET_MY_TABLE
    like MY_TABLE
    USING org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc
    OPTIONS (
    ^^^
      url "jdbc:mysql://XX.XX.XX.XX:3306/test?useSSL=FALSE&nullCatalogMeansCurrent=true&zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull",
      driver "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver",
      dbtable "MY_TABLE",
      user "username",
      password "password"
    )
```

Any idea how to create a PARQUET table using any jdbc data source?

Comment: Have you tried USING JDBC or USING 'org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc' syntax ?
Do you really need both USING and STORED AS parameters ?

Comment: I used org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc, without STORED table is in Hadoop format